# How to add unique IDs to a data frame in R based on a sequence of incremental, non-consecutive numbers

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID  Ixs Ixe Lem1 Lem2
1   0   1   S-      S-  
2   1   2   P       P   
3   0   1   T       t   
4   1   2   1       1   
5   0   1   W       w   
6   1   2   Na      Nadd
7   3   4   Cze     Czec
8   5   6   Abch    Ab
9   7   8   Gr      grn
10  9   10  Grs     grs
11  0   1   Cz      Czc
```

Each number sequence in column `Ixs`, starting with 0, belongs to the same observation. The sequences are incremental but not consecutive. I'd need to have an extra column with an ID counter that would assign consecutive IDs whenever there's a 0 in `Ixs`:

```
ID  Ixs Ixe Lem1 Lem2  SeqID
1   0   1   S-      S-   1  
2   1   2   P       P    1  
3   0   1   T       t    2  
4   1   2   1       1    2
5   0   1   W       w    3  
6   1   2   Na      Nadd 3 
7   3   4   Cze     Czec 3
8   5   6   Abch    Ab   3
9   7   8   Gr      grn  3
10  9   10  Grs     grs  3
11  0   1   Cz      Czc  4
```

All the solutions I've seen to add a integer sequence require some grouping variable I don't have. Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cumsum` on a logical vector in `base R`

```
df1$SeqID <- cumsum(df1$Ixs == 0)
df1$SeqID
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:11, Ixs = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 7L, 9L, 0L), Ixe = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 
10L, 1L), Lem1 = c("S-", "P", "T", "1", "W", "Na", "Cze", "Abch", 
"Gr", "Grs", "Cz"), Lem2 = c("S-", "P", "t", "1", "w", "Nadd", 
"Czec", "Ab", "grn", "grs", "Czc")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `findInterval()` from base R

```
df <- within(df,SeqID <- findInterval(seq(nrow(df)),which(Ixs==0)))
```

such that

```
> df
   ID Ixs Ixe Lem1 Lem2 SeqID
1   1   0   1   S-   S-     1
2   2   1   2    P    P     1
3   3   0   1    T    t     2
4   4   1   2    1    1     2
5   5   0   1    W    w     3
6   6   1   2   Na Nadd     3
7   7   3   4  Cze Czec     3
8   8   5   6 Abch   Ab     3
9   9   7   8   Gr  grn     3
10 10   9  10  Grs  grs     3
11 11   0   1   Cz  Czc     4
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:11, Ixs = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 7L, 9L, 0L), Ixe = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 
10L, 1L), Lem1 = c("S-", "P", "T", "1", "W", "Na", "Cze", "Abch", 
"Gr", "Grs", "Cz"), Lem2 = c("S-", "P", "t", "1", "w", "Nadd", 
"Czec", "Ab", "grn", "grs", "Czc")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using `data.table` and `zoo`:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

setDT(df)[Ixs == 0, SeqID := 1:.N][, SeqID := na.locf(SeqID, na.rm = F)]

#    ID Ixs Ixe Lem1 Lem2 SeqID
#1:  1   0   1   S-   S-     1
#2:  2   1   2    P    P     1
#3:  3   0   1    T    t     2
#4:  4   1   2    1    1     2
#5:  5   0   1    W    w     3
#6:  6   1   2   Na Nadd     3
#7:  7   3   4  Cze Czec     3
#8:  8   5   6 Abch   Ab     3
#9:  9   7   8   Gr  grn     3
#10: 10  9  10  Grs  grs     3
#11: 11  0   1   Cz  Czc     4
```

## data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:11, Ixs = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 
                                  5L, 7L, 9L, 0L), Ixe = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 
                                                           10L, 1L), Lem1 = structure(c(9L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 11L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 
                                                                                        5L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "Abch", "Cz", "Cze", "Gr", "Grs", 
                                                                                                                "Na", "P", "S-", "T", "W"), class = "factor"), Lem2 = structure(c(9L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                  8L, 10L, 1L, 11L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "Ab", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "Czc", "Czec", "grn", "grs", "Nadd", "P", "S-", "t", "w"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           -11L))
```